# How to have sound go to a usb mono headset?

Tags: sound, usb, mono, headset

I have a new usb mono headset. I want to know how to make all of the sound go to the mono headset...I already set that up for Skype but other than that, it goes to the speakers instead of the headset. Any fixes? Also, I am running Esound.

EDIT: I have TeamViewer, so if anyone really know what to do...add me on Facebook : Kevin Maghuyop
EDIT 2: i removed pulseaudio because i had a problem with the audio jacks....and now i dont use them and I have a problem.

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 2):

right Click on speaker icon, then  click on playback device.
Then Select your headset and below change drop down lsit box to default.
Done :)

Comment: I tried but i cant do anything :(

Comment: @KevinMaghuyop you can try in the terminal: `sudo alsamixer` and check if your headset is enabled, but I don't know any solutions longer than this.